# JPA - Parameter value [604800000] was not matching type [java.lang.Double]

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I try to delete rows from a table that lived more than a given time in days. The `start` of a row is a timestamp.

```
EntityManager em = ...
long interval = ... // long value read from a properties file

String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE current_timestamp() - start > :interval";
String jpql = String.format(template , MyClass.class.getCanonicalName());

Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setParameter("interval", TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(interval));
q.executeUpdate();
```

**MyClass.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROWS")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6070604872038740340L;

    puyblic MyClass() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "start", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date start;

    // getters ans setters...
}
```

However, I get the following exception :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [604800000] was not matching type [java.lang.Double]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:360)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:364)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have an interval field on MyClass?

Comment: @KevinBowersox No I haven't

Comment: @Alex Only to point out: it should be `current_timestamp()` and the start property in MyClass should be better a numeric type, if you want to use it in some computation. As `current_timestamp()` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` the parameter `:interval` might be expected as a `java.util.Date` instead of long/Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how I solve my problem:

Instead of doing a calculation AND then a comparison in JPQL, I do all the calculation in my Java code. The final comparison is left to JPQL.

```
String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE start < :calculatedStop";
String jpql = String.format(template , MyClass.class.getCanonicalName());

long calculatedStop = new java.util.Date().getTime() - INTERVAL;// INTERVAL is a constant

Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setParameter("calculatedStop", calculatedStop);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple.

`String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE current_timestamp() - start > :interval";`
Building this query Hibernate expects this interval value to be of type Double.

So doing this solves your problem:

```
q.setParameter("interval", (double)TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(interval));
```

We all expect Java to be able to convert from long to double if needed. But since the long value is boxed Hibernate simply tries to **cast** Long to Double, which is indeed not fruitful in no means.

So if you convert it to double first it gets boxed to Double and Double is obviously castable to Double.

**So where does the Double comes from?**

I checked the implementation of the SqlDate and Date type and both map to date and are able to convert from and to long values. Also timestamp is mapped to Date.

So I tried this:

`String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE current_timestamp() > :interval";`
And it failed since Hibernate complains about Long is not compatible with java.util.Date. So using only current_timestamp() maps to a Date value.

The same is true for this:

`String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE start > :interval";`

The double comes into play when one tries to substract a Date from another Date. So using any of:
`String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE current_timestamp() - current_timestamp() > :interval";`
or
`String template = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE start - start > :interval";`

interval is expected to be a double since the result of Date - Date is expected to be a Double value. And that is why Hibernate is complaining about.

A bit weird but that is the way it is and that is the exact explanation of what is going on.

Comment: I have tried you solution. But now Postgresql complains that there is no operator `>` working with `timestamp with time zone` on one hand and `double precision` on the other hand :(

Comment: I reproduced the problem using h2 not postgre. So I only used a timestamp (no time zone). Did you ever considered using Long values for timestamps? Using long for timestamps (UTC) often is the best idea in terms of timestamping.

You can use plain SQL queries (session.createSQLQuery). Try it and Hibernate wont force you to use Double values in first place. As far as I remember SQL queries are like using jdbc directly. Try to get it work and report what type postgre is expecting to work with '>'.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the HSQL. The problem might be related to currentTimestamp and start. I can not think of it being HSQL keywords or valid properties.

Have you tried using unnamed parameters and set the parameter using its index?

**Update**:

Your setup appears to be not correct. You want to make arithmetic calculations with a String (start).

I did something similar lately. I just have a task that I set the time to and after that I check if the task timed out (not done but a timestamp smaller then before).

Here is some code:

**1/ Mapping**

```
long timestamp = 0; //default is 0
```

**2/ Set timestamp**

```
task.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); session.getTransaction().commit()
```

**3/ Query for timed out methods**

```
   session.beginTransaction();
   long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task.class);
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("done", false));
   criteria.add(Restrictions.le("timestamp", currentTime - Task.TASK_TIMEOUT));
   Task task = (Task)criteria.uniqueResult();
   if(task != null) {
        task.setTimestamp(currentTime);
   }
   session.getTransaction().commit();
```

You can see I just use the criteria search here since it is simplier. Also note that I use uniqueResult but you can easily change it to retrieve a list.

Comment: I have changed `currentTimestamp` to `current_timestamp ` with no more luck. BTW I have added the missing `start` field I mentionned in my question.

Comment: I need to delete rows... a CriteriaQuery is not suitable here.

Comment: Have you tried using createSQLQuery and access the table directly? Since you are using basic SQL functionality such a simple delete statement should be processable by almost all SQL/Database dialects. This way you can get at least the functionality implemented and when it is working you can compare your version of  the working SQL statement with the one Hibernate generates.

Comment: I will reproduce your entity and try it myself. I overlooked the type conversion problem. I will add another answer.